# Two touchscreen same product and vendor ids, needs to invert one

Tags: touchscreen, xinput, lsusb

I have 2 touchscreens with same name and same vendor:product id we using lsusb command and xinput id changes after reboot. I needs to invert the touch for one of the touchscreen, and this is my output of xinput list-props, how to identify the touchscreen and apply transformation to it on startup?

```
Device 'ILITEK ILITEK-TP': Device Enabled (152): 1 Coordinate Transformation Matrix (153): -0.500000, 0.000000, 0.500000, 0.000000, -1.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000 libinput Calibration Matrix (283): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000 libinput Calibration Matrix Default (284): 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 0.000000, 1.000000 libinput Send Events Modes Available (285): 1, 0 libinput Send Events Mode Enabled (286): 0, 0 libinput Send Events Mode Enabled Default (287): 0, 0 Device Node (288): "/dev/input/event9" Device Product ID (289): 8746, 1 |
```

To identify the touchscreen using some script and get invert that.